# Preventing xcode from trying to parse html

Tags: xcode

Xcode is trying to validate a local html as swift in my bundle. How do I tell xcode to ignore this html file?

[image: xcode is trying to validate html as swift]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have messed up Xcode somehow. Xcode thinks it's a source code file, not a simple resource.

Click View > Utilities > Show Files Inspector (or press `Cmd + Opt + 1`). Then select the appropriate type for your HTML file.

[image: File Type Selector]

Comment: awesome. i had to restart xcode too in order to zero out the old errors (cleaning my build folder was not enough)